# Issue with the payment flow using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've a scenario where I need to automate the payment page.

I need to enter the credit card details, but the thing is when I use sendkeys method to type the text, it doesn't take the full card number though it only takes the first 4 chars.

The card field is designed in such a way that it takes 4 numbers and then provide auto space and then next 4 numbers and so on...

How would I handle this particular thing?

Comment: can you please post some code? it is going to be hard to help without seeing some example.

Comment: It has diff. 4 boxes to accept digits like 4-4-4-4 OR it has only one text box and allow to enter 16 digits with space at each 4 digits?

Comment: it has only 1 box to accept all of them...

I was just using `driver.findElement(By.id("id")).sendkeys("121212121212...");`

Comment: Please provide us the payment link, and if not then search for similar and provide us the link...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as this code sends the character one by one and I hope that the payment gateway will accept the cardnumber if the characters are sent one by one.

```
for(int i=0;i<ccNumber.length();i++){
            creditcardtextbox.sendKeys(ccNumber.substring(i).split(""));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, using Python and Selenium and the credit card field only takes 4 characters

Here is the code

```
#move to the Shipping screen
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#move to the Payment, no return key here, press the button
driver.implicitly_wait(1) # seconds
driver.find_element_by_name("button").click()
#enter the payment details
driver.implicitly_wait(1) # seconds

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_number")
elem.send_keys(str(sys.argv[5]), Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_name")
elem.send_keys(str(sys.argv[6]))
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_month")
elem.send_keys(str(sys.argv[7]))
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_year")
elem.send_keys(str(sys.argv[8]))
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_verification_value")
elem.send_keys(str(sys.argv[9]), Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by :
`driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_number").sendKeys("5123");
driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_number").sendKeys("4567");
driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_number").sendKeys("8901");
driver.find_element_by_id("checkout_credit_card_number").sendKeys("2346");`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution mocked in Python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

ccn = '4111111111111111'
ccn_locator = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'numberField')
for num in ccn.replace('', ' ').strip().split():
    ccn_locator.send_keys(num)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like below to handle space between every 4 digits :

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("elementid")).sendKeys("1");
    driver.findElement(By.id("elementid")).sendKeys("2");
    driver.findElement(By.id("elementid")).sendKeys("3");
    driver.findElement(By.id("elementid")).sendKeys("5");
    driver.findElement(By.id("elementid")).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
    driver.findElement(By.id("elementid")).sendKeys("5");
    driver.findElement(By.id("elementid")).sendKeys("1");
    driver.findElement(By.id("elementid")).sendKeys("2");
    driver.findElement(By.id("elementid")).sendKeys("3");
    driver.findElement(By.id("elementid")).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
```

Above is sample code , please replace your actual element ID and digits. Also I have given just sample for 8 digits , you can do same for 16 digits. Just call that SPACE key after every 4 digits. Your elementid will be same for all lines.

**Note** : There may be other way to do above but I have tried above and working fine so suggesting you same.